# Necessary and sufficient conditions for pseudo Riemannian manifold to be time orientable

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, characteristic-classes, spin-geometry, orientation, stiefel-whitney

It is well known that a smooth manifold $M$ is orientable if the first Stiefel-Whitney class of the tangent bundle vanishes. In particular, this implies that if $M$ is equipped with a pseudo-Riemannian metric of signature $(t,s)$, then the frame bundle $O(M)$ admits a reduction to a principal $SO(t,s)$ bundle under the embedding $SO(t,s)\hookrightarrow O(t,s)$.

Now, let $SO^+(t,s)$ denote the Lie subgroup of $SO(t,s)$ consisting of the linear isometries of $\mathbb{R}^{t,s}$ which preserve the orientation of any maximally negative definite subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{t,s}$. The pseudo Riemannian manifold is then orientable and time orientable if the frame bundle $O(M)$ admits a reduction to a principal $SO^+(t,s)$ bundle under the embedding $SO^+(t,s)\hookrightarrow O(t,s)$. Is there a characteristic class related to this result?

I am asking because any orientable and time orientable pseudo Riemmanian manifolds admits a $\text{Spin}^+(t,s)$ structure if and only if the second Stiefel-Whitney class of $TM$ vanishes. If instead $M$ is just orientable, then I imagine that $M$ would admit a $\text{Spin}(t,s)$ structure if and only if the second Stiefel-Whitney class vanishes. However, I am unsure of when general orientable pseudo Riemannian manifolds which are also spin admit a $\text{Spin}^+(t,s)$ structure, i.e. when can we conclude that a pseudo Riemannian manifold that is spin, is also $\text{spin}^+$?

In the Lorentzian case, then we get a time orientation for free, as a necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of a Lorentz metric is a nowhere vanishing vector field, which would easily supply us with a time orientation.

I would guess that if there exists a vector bundle isomorphism:
$$TM\cong E^t\oplus E^s$$
where the vector bundle $E^t$ has vanishing first Stiefel-Whitney class, then $TM$ is time orientable, but I am honestly unsure. Any source, or collection of sources that systematically treats existence of spin structures, and time orientations in the pseudo Riemannian case would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this covered in George Whiston's paper "Lorentzian characteristic classes" GRG (1975)?

Comment: @RyanBudney was unaware of this paper, but I’ll check it out

Comment: @RyanBudney I don't think this is covered in Whiston's paper. He does not really mention time orientability in depth out side of the $(1,3)$ case

Comment: Hi Chris, but I think it's the exact same argument.  You have a Stiefel-Whitney class for each sub-bundle, the first sub-bundle is orientable if the $w_1$ class for that sub-bundle is trivial.  The 2nd is orientable if its $w_1$ class is trivial.   So if I understand which notion of orientability you are interested in, it would be the one for the timelike subspace, i.e. you want a timelike sense of direction.

Comment: @RyanBudney Ok, so that's pretty much what I said in the my last paragraph?

Comment: Right, your first paragraph, but adapted to the decomposition $TM \simeq E^t \oplus E^s$.  This decomposition you get by arguing that the full-rank timelike (or spacelike) subspaces of a vector space with non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form, they are a convex space.  So you piece together the decomposition of the tangent bundle fibrewise, with a partition of unity argument.

Comment: @RyanBudney I see that makes sense. If you would like to expand on your comment with an answer I will award it the bounty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question I believe the answer is yes.  Almost certainly it's in the literature but I do not know this literature very well.

The idea is as you suggested.  Maximal-rank timelike (or spacelike) vector subspaces form a convex space.  So you paste together local decompositions using a partition of unity to decompose the tangent bundle of your Lorentz manifold into an orthogonal direct-sum of a maximal timelike sub-bundle and a maximal space-like subbundle.

You then have characteristic classes for the sub-bundles, and $w_1$ of your timelike sub-bundle is the obstruction you are looking for.